# Conditionally creating members inside a class

Tags: c++, class, c++17, if-constexpr

Is it possible to do something like:

```
template <unsigned majorVer, unsigned minorVer>
class Object
{
public:

    if constexpr ((majorVer == 1) && (minorVer > 10))
        bool newField;
    else
        int newInt
};
```

or

```
template <unsigned majorVer, unsigned minorVer>
class Object
{
public:

    if constexpr ((majorVer == 1) && (minorVer > 10))
        bool newField;
    // Nothing other wise
};
```

using c++17? 
I would like to change the structure of a class based on some condition that can be checked at compile time. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Template specialisation.

Comment: This thing is possible in D language with `static if` construct but in C++ you need to play games with inheritance from `std::condtitional_t<your condition, struct with member, empty struct>` and rely on empty base optimization. A good talk from Andrei Alexandrescu about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcyb1lpEHm0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `if constexpr` for this. You would have to collapse them into one member using something like [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
std::conditional_t<(majorVer == 1) && (minorVer > 10), bool, int> newField;
```

Alternatively, you can wrap each of the two kinds of the fields in their own type:

```
struct A { bool newField; };
struct B { int newInt; };
```

And either inherit from `std::conditional_t<???, A, B>` or have one of those as a member.

---

For the case where you want either a member or nothing, the other case just needs to be an empty type. In C++20, that's:

```
struct E { };
[[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<some_condition(), bool, E> newField;
```

In C++17 and earlier, you'll want to inherit from this to ensure that the empty base optimization kicks in:

```
struct B { bool field; };
struct E { };

template <unsigned majorVer, unsigned minorVer>
class Object : private std::conditional_t<some_condition(), B, E>
{ ... };
```

Comment: Thanks Barry for the answer. What if I want to create a member only when the condition is satisfied(No member needs to be there otherwise)? Can that be done too using conditional_t?

Comment: @Arun Sure, have the alternative be some empty type.

Comment: @Barry this will create member with an empty type, which is not the same as no member at all.

Comment: @Barry Ideally as n.m has mentioned, I would like that no members are created at all. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: @arun inherit from an empty struct.

Comment: @n.m. Tomato, tomato? It's basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

if-constexpr is about control flow, not about memory layout. Maybe the reflection TS could be a good fit for this. However, untill that is available, you'll need other techniques.

```
 constexpr bool useLegacyInt(unsigned major, unsigned minor)
 {
      return (majorVer <= 1) && (minorVer <= 10));
 }

  template<bool>
  class ObjectBase
  {
        book newField;
   };

   template<>
  class ObjectBase<true>
  {
        int newInt;
   };

   template <unsigned majorVer, unsigned minorVer>
   class Object : public ObjectBase<useLegacyInt (majorVer, minorVer)>
   {};
```

Based on this, you could do some refinements. You don't only influence the members, also the methods. So also setters and getters ... could have a different signature. Protected helper functions could provide a bool API to Object to separate the implementation.

Finally, I would not recommend using a bool, I rather expect an enumeration as this can have multiple values.

Inheriting from an earlier version could also be possible if a new version only extends. And with some default template arguments, you can even do more fancy things.

Be warned, this kind of backwards compatibility could become complex really quickly. Sometimes it's better to just copy the complete code in a legacy version and keep it as is, without interference of the new API. This at the cost of duplicated code.